# Gradle build multiple .war files with different properties file

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, war

We are developing a new web application from scratch using Spring Boot and relevant dependencies and is built using Gradle.

Our project has almost 5 stages of testing, with each stage executing on a different server and thus end up with slightly different configuration on each server.

The above scenario is a very common situation and usually it is a practice I followed in my earlier projects to save the "Properties" file directly under the server's classpath so that the same .war file can be deployed on multiple servers and still have different configuration based on the server/environment.

Now, the obvious disadvantage with the above setup is that - such a setup cannot be easily shared with other developers through some version controller. And further I cant use the power of "Process Resources" task in Gradle to introduce some dynamic properties during build process.

Now, If I pull the .properties file within the project setup, then I can easily version control it, sharing becomes easier and I also can introduce dynamic properties through Gradle. The disadvantage being that I might have to prepare multiple .war files after updating the .properties file.

There are two questions I have?

1. What would be your thought on the above 2 ways? Given this situation what would you choose and why (Any other way of dealing with this scenario)?
2. In the 2nd case of building multiple .war files, how do i re-run the war task to generate a new output file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should build one war for all environments. Set an os envvar per environment (ex spring.profile=dev, spring.profile=prod).

Read the right property file based on that envvar(spring will do this for you). Ex application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties

Store production db connection passwords in envvars while you're at it.

See

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I'm exactly doing that.. since 99% of the properties are the same, I have to push all my properties into appliation.properties. And then since I can only control the active profile from application.properties only, I also have the variable portion (spring.profile) as well in the same file. Thus, I end up with the 2 scenarios I described above..

Comment: @FirstX what do you mean "control the active profile"? you don't set the active profile in your properties file, you set it in an OS env var . Also, you can have more than one properties file

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is possible to roll all properties files into the war and build in some "profile" logic, and you actually might have this since you are using Spring. [Spring does support "profiles"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) based on the value of a system level property.

Another approach that I have used in the past is to "build" the properties files at build time. I have done this with Gradle.  Essentially you have a runtime properties file "template" with placeholders for each environmentally specific property and a properties file of properties that is conditionally pull into your Gradle project and used by the 'expand' method in a Gradle copy task. You might target your environment with a command-line property like `-Penv=PROD`.

Your war task might depend on another task, `buildRuntimeProperties` or something. This build the environment specific properties. At this point you have to decide how to handle your build artifact:

1. Build the properties file into the war and publish each env-specific war to your artifact repo with an identifying version or artifact ID
2. Manage the properties file separately and keep the war environment agnostic and tool your property resolution code to be able to look up the properties outside the war.

Comment: Can you provide any code snippet or link? I want to follow the second approach but don't know how to do that.